# Solve integer linear system

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I want to find a solution of the system
$$A x = 0,\quad x>0,\ x\in\mathbb{Z}^d$$
where the matrix $A$ has integer entries. With a single solution I am happy. There is a way to do this? If not, can you recommend me a software that will do this?

Comment: Try the `NullSpace` function.

Comment: See the tutorial on [`Solving Linear Systems`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingLinearSystems.html) in the Documentation Center

Comment: One possibility: Make the list of equations that this corresponds to, then us [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) with `Integers` as the domain.

Comment: the problem with NullSpace is that it give me real solutions; I need positive integers solution. I'll try with FindInstance

Comment: If `A` is comprised of nonnegative values, then any nontrivial null vector will have negatives.

Comment: uups, only x has integer entries

Comment: Then I'd say go with `FindInstance` for one solution. For the full set, could use `Solve` an in [an old response on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_effectively_determine_if_there_exists_a_positive_integer_solution_for_a_homogeneous_system_of_linear_equations). It would be helpful here to have a concrete example, by the way.

Comment: How big is $A$ typically? I found NullSpace to give me rational answers for some matrices I experimented with, up to 500 x 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `NullSpace[ ]` works for me. Create a 500 x 500 matrix of integers

```
mat = Table[RandomInteger[20], {500}, {500}];
```

Lower its rank by replacing the first row with the last, resulting in a non-zero null space

```
mat[[1]] = mat // Last;
```

Unleash NullSpace[ ]

```
ns = NullSpace[mat]//Flatten;
```

Take a look at an element of the null space

```
ns[[250]]
```

> 1216466034899617700009841434407142132740354076698767801084521189694612\
>   2511069260034455762795401734087601141005623713828124692569095816463659\
>   2710502589527463938986193921763074208901887835981221417119041072827306\
>   4631271757749595053183961653203952731021162016064130272587654354938130\
>   2166261586109017842591056055927581261585252713938627078707082256186125\
>   2454225107993701187501220538575122471488423940694811844961551632217472\
>   7402283346491551671146711131036290870399960289049677405962387124913893\
>   5129941213575270691366951939914110163294844744326279867757146219372314\
>   9758713975561168144837106718996451652246452647671496605241216527957861\
>   2489768530913764183650725469305319561271500664761383195214912693747729\
>   8388438602988835098926610409905688093997412246500694337854741505734072\
>   7841449258005930727929096262351940939259156637223692609679347619853288\
>   1158801817186466110391244408712790232571183882259409557714353628382559\
>   56967261900582775599830869555089887212760688681

If the rows in your null space have at least one that is mixed term (positive and negative) then it is an easy solve from there.

Did fine up to 2000 x 2000 too. Make sure you are keeping everything rational, with no decimal points appearing anywhere in your $A$ matrix.